# Not able to add bootstrap in angular 2 application

Tags: angular

```
I am trying to add the bootstrap class style.css file.When i am compiling the 
 application getting the below error.
```

**style.css**

@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

```
**Myerror**
```

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css
Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in 'F:\guna\dreamapp\src'
    at onError (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
    at F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (F:\guna\dreamapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
 @ ./src/styles.css 4:14-138
 @ multi ./src/styles.css

Comment: You can check several bootstrap getting started guides here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most probably something wrong in the path to import bootstrap. I don't know whether or not it is a good practice to import it directly from CSS, but here is the Angular CLI way to get bootstrap:

`npm install bootstrap@3 --save`

And then in your .angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

**NB:** In case you want to use Bootstrap 4 alpha, to install it:

`npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 --save`

and the name of the JS file to import is then `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error with Angular CLI 1.6.4 try to roll back to 1.6.3 for now.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9080

Comment: just use npm to install version 1.6.3 `npm install --save @angular/cli@1.6.3`